# como obtener solamente el dia de la fecha actual en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Como podría obtener el día de mi fecha actual, así obtengo mi fecha actual :

```
$scope.CurrentDate = new Date();
```

Pero el día como lo obtengo?

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza la función `getDay()` de JavaScript.

```
var dateDay = new Date().getDay();
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera sería a través de javascript puro:

Para retornar por ejemplo el nombre a partir del número:

```
function getDia(index){
    var dia = new Array(7);
    dia[0] = "Domingo";
    dia[1] = "Lunes";
    dia[2] = "Martes";
    dia[3] = "Miércoles";
    dia[4] = "Jueves";
    dia[5] = "Viernes";
    dia[6] = "Sábado";
  return dia[index];

}
```

Para usarla

```
var d = new Date(); // Por ejemplo 1
var n = getDia(d.getDay());
```

El resultado:

**Lunes**

Y para obtener el número del día se usa el método getDate().

```
d.getDate() // Por ej: 22
```

Ejemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3OYdYTNfNq8b5t5Nnnh?p=preview

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, sino, no dudes en volver a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: excelente gracias, el método que necesitaba era el getDate()

Comment: Excelente, saludos